# React Router returns blank page with correct pathing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react. I'm following a tutorial, and my code is exactly the same as the tutorial, but the result isn't. Basically, my page routes are returning a blank page. There's no error in the console, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here's my code

**Homepage.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Login from "./Login";
import CreateUser from "./CreateUser";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link,
  Redirect,
} from "react-router-dom";

export default class HomePage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <p>This is the homepage</p>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route path="/createuser" component={CreateUser} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

**Login.js Component**

```
 import React, { Component } from "react";
export default class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return <p>This is the Login Page</p>;
  }
}
```

**CreateUser.js Component**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
export default class CreateUser extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return <p>This is the Create User Page</p>;
  }
}
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "React";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import HomePage from "./HomePage";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <HomePage />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const appDiv = document.getElementById("app"); // get 'app' div
render(<App />, appDiv); // place App component into app div
```

I've tried changing the import "react" code in line 1 to import 'react' among other things.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Typo, you need to include the "/" path prefix for your routes, i.e. "/login" and "/createuser".

Comment: That doesn't fix the issue, I also removed the forward slashes to see if that would fix the problem, and posted that code here accidently. Let me fix it.

Comment: Well, I can assure you that with the code provided it works, so I suspect you are also using `Link` components and perhaps those aren't working as expected. Can you share a complete code example that reproduces the issue along with a set of reproduction steps?

Comment: I have imported Link components from 'react-router-dom', however they're not being used at all. The only code I can provide as an example are the snippets posted above. I should clarify I am also building the backend of the site I'm working on in Django. So maybe it's a problem with my urls.py file. I'll check it out.

Comment: That's what was wrong! The my url configuration.

Comment: Well, whatever you are able to share doesn't need to be any protected proprietary code, it just needs to accurately reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the paths to "/login" and "/createuser" in Homepage.js

Comment: That doesn't fix the issue, I also removed the forward slashes to see if that would fix the problem, and posted that code here accidently. Let me fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Django on the backend of the React project I'm working on. The routes were not connected to the url.py file for the url configuration for my Django app.